# Remove index.php from prerender htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, prerender

I am using the prerender.io javascript middleware to render JS pages on my website.

The htaccess middleware code is as follows.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bing|msnbot|yandex|yahoo|baidu|facebook|screaming|siteliner|ahrefsbot|dmca.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Prerender} !1

    # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.svg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/$2 [P,L]
```

The issue with this, on my server at least (but not on some others) is index.php is added to the url sent to the service, which causes an error.

EG: https://www.example.com/index.php

Is it possible to stop that?

EG: https://www.example.com/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want to check googlebot, bingbot, or yandex by their user agents since they support the _escaped_fragment_ crawling protocol. Checking them by their user agent can get you penalized for cloaking.

Try changing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.svg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/$2 [P,L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.svg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(index.php)?(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/$3 [P,L]
```

Notice the addition of (index.php)? and change of $2 to $3. Also, don't forget to change www.example.com to your domain.